# Commit entities immediately using JPA Spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am somewhat new to both Spring and JPA. I am writing a spring batch application using Spring boot. I am using `JpaRepository` to write into database. My data is not getting saved to database immediately. It gets saved after the sometime only.  I have tried both `save()` and `saveAndFlush()`. I think spring boot is overriding the functionality of `flush()`. How do I make it save the data immediately? Is there a way to configure the flush mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like your transactions are longer than you want them to be.

Comment: @JensSchauder yes. Is there a way to handle this? Surely there must be one ;-)

Comment: Just make your transactions as short as you need them. How you do that depends on how you control your transactions but is normally pretty straightforward. If you need help, please update your question with a minimal example demonstrating the current behavior.

Comment: Spring Batch controls the transaction and will commit data after all elements of your chunk have been processed. You have a tx per chunk and not per element (I also doubt you want to have a tx per element as that would severely impact performance).